# Getting error when trying to initialize nested array "The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access."

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an object whith an array and inside this a second array, just like this.

```
export class OrdenCompra {
public id?: number,
public insumos?: OrdenCompraInsumo[],
}

export class OrdenCompraInsumo {
id?: number;
traslados?: IImpuestoTraslado[];
}

export class ImpuestoTraslado{
public id?: number,
public impuesto?: number
}
```

i want to add some value to

> traslados

like this

```
const retencion = new ImpuestoRetencion();
ordenCompra?.insumos[index]?.retenciones?.push(retencion);
```

but at this point

> ordenCompra?.insumos[index]?.retenciones?

it is

> undefined

so the value it is never assigned.

if i try to initialize i get an error.

> ordenCompra?.insumos[index]?.retenciones = []

or

> ordenCompra?.insumos[index]?.retenciones = ImpuestoRetencion[];

or

> ordenCompra?.insumos[index]?.retenciones: ImpuestoRetencion[] || [];

which says

> The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.

so i have not been able to assign  a value to this array. i know this is a very trivial question but even when i have search for hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?.`, known as [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) is only useful for reading/invoking, not for setting. From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining):

> At its core, optional chaining lets us write code where TypeScript can immediately stop running some expressions if we run into a `null` or `undefined`.

So you might interpret `const foobarbaz = foo?.bar?.baz` like this:

```
// Will have type: undefined | typeof baz
const foobarbaz = foo === undefined || foo === null
                    ? undefined
                    : foo.bar === undefined || foo.bar === null
                      ? undefined
                      : foo.bar.baz
```

This makes no sense in the context of a set because you cannot set null or undefined to a value:

```
foo?.bar?.baz = foobarbaz
// ^^^^^^^^^^ - The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be
//                an optional property access.

// Practically the same as:
(foo === undefined || foo === null
  ? undefined
  : foo.bar === undefined || foo.bar === null
    ? undefined
    : foo.bar.baz) = foobarbaz
```

To set this property, you must check that the value of `foo.bar.baz` is not nullish. This can be done by wrapping the assignment in an `if` statement:

```
foo.bar.baz = something; // error!

if(foo?.bar?.baz) {
  foo.bar.baz = something; // OK
}
```

If you know that your value isn't null or undefined but the compiler isn't able to determine this on its own, use the [non-null assertion operator (`!.`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
foo!.bar!.baz = something; // OK
```

[Here is a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIBGcUA-AFw76EEkBelyIArgLZHQ0EC%20ufuBOhABnMMhiYqGLAB9kLEABMIMUBCXIAvNTqkqeWgyoBGAAxmafAZPRkAdCXKO49bchPmA3LlsuoLm46nmY%20uMAwyAAUtg5Oca4AlLoSmP6B7iE%20NpgAhP75DJneuEA) demonstrating each of these senarios.

Comment: thank you, i just realice that removing the ? character allow to set the value.